# Are there any modern (Moose/PSGI) web frameworks other than Catalyst?

Tags: perl, web-frameworks, moose, psgi

Are there any Perl web-development frameworks other than Catalyst that are:

- written with [`Moose`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose)
- natively written for PSGI (not with some PSGI-emulation)
- Unicode ready/safe - so Perl 5.10+
- small, extensible and nice

or is [`Catalyst`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Catalyst) the **only** guy in the town? :)

AFAIK, [`Dancer`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Dancer), [`Mojolicious`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Mojolicious), [`Jifty`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Jifty) are not Moose-core

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my favorite one - [Mason](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Mason/).

- Moose based
- default web-agnostic and PSGI native [with PSGIHandler plugin](http://search.cpan.org/~jswartz/Mason-Plugin-PSGIHandler-0.06/lib/Mason/Plugin/PSGIHandler.pm)
- its utf8 support is can be done with plugin [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858596/how-to-make-mason2-utf8-clean/6807411#6807411)

It is usually used as templating engine only, but with some discipline you can use it as VC framework (read: not enforcing separation and doing nothing for Models, Views are natural, Controllers you can done with dhandlers and [with the RouterSimple plugin](http://search.cpan.org/~jswartz/Mason-Plugin-RouterSimple-0.05/lib/Mason/Plugin/RouterSimple.pm)).

Comment: Too clarify, Mason is Mason 2.0, where HTML::Mason (also called Mason) is Mason 1.x.  Just saw a presentation on Mason by J Swartz.  Model stuff you should be handling in normal Perl modules.  V&C he believes should be more tightly coupled due to his experience that shows them as already coupled.  I haven't tried it yet, but it looks very interesting, it fixes some of what bugged be about HTML::Mason, yet retains the philosophy of doing the minimum needed to make a great templating language.  Between PSGI middleware and available plugins, Mason should give you a solid platform to build on.

Answer (score 10):

The only other one that comes to my mind os [Ox](https://github.com/stevan/Ox). It's a pretty nice framework in many ways and does match all of your requirements. Sadly, though, its user base is somewhat small and you'll end up re-inventing a lot of things you could've ready re-used off of CPAN if you had gone with Catalyst. But sometimes that's just what you want to do for certain applications, so I'm happy it exists.