# Mason2 wrong utf8 encoding with the "go" method

Tags: perl, mason

Bit long question, because AFAIK Poet/Mason2 isn't the very often used framework - so I'm trying to be detailed.

Two years ago I [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858596/how-to-make-mason2-utf-8-clean) how to make Mason2 utf8 clean. As far as i know, here isn't much new in Mason/Poet in this field - and unfortunately today I meet **another problem**. Simple test case:

```
$ poet new my   #create new poet application
$ cd my
```

Override some methods, allowing to use utf8 in the components:

add to `./lib/My/Mason/Compilation.pm`

```
override 'output_class_header' => sub {
    return join("\n",
        super(), qq(
            use utf8;
            use Encode qw(encode decode);
        )
    );
};
```

The above adds to each compiled Mason component the `use utf8...`.

Also need encode the output from Mason (Plack need bytes), so in: `./lib/My/Mason/Request.pm`

```
override 'run' => sub {
    my($self, $path, $args) = @_;
    my $result = super();
    $result->output( Encode::encode('UTF-8', $result->output()) );
    return $result;
};
```

Now, can create a component such `page.mc` for example with a content:

```
% sub { uc($_[0]) } {{
a quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
διαφυλάξτε γενικά τη ζωή σας από βαθειά ψυχικά τραύματα.
árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép.
dość gróźb fuzją, klnę, pych i małżeństw!
эх, чужак, общий съём цен шляп (юфть) – вдрызг!
kŕdeľ šťastných ďatľov učí pri ústí váhu mĺkveho koňa obhrýzať kôru a žrať čerstvé mäso.
zwölf boxkämpfer jagen viktor quer über den großen sylter deich.
% }}
```

After running a poet app `bin/run.pl` you can go to: `http://0:5000/page` and will get a correct content.

> A QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG. ΔΙΑΦΥΛΆΞΤΕ ΓΕΝΙΚΆ ΤΗ ΖΩΉ
>   ΣΑΣ ΑΠΌ ΒΑΘΕΙΆ ΨΥΧΙΚΆ ΤΡΑΎΜΑΤΑ. ÁRVÍZTŰRŐ TÜKÖRFÚRÓGÉP. DOŚĆ GRÓŹB
>   FUZJĄ, KLNĘ, PYCH I MAŁŻEŃSTW! ЭХ, ЧУЖАК, ОБЩИЙ СЪЁМ ЦЕН ШЛЯП (ЮФТЬ) –
>   ВДРЫЗГ! KŔDEĽ ŠŤASTNÝCH ĎATĽOV UČÍ PRI ÚSTÍ VÁHU MĹKVEHO KOŇA OBHRÝZAŤ
>   KÔRU A ŽRAŤ ČERSTVÉ MÄSO. ZWÖLF BOXKÄMPFER JAGEN VIKTOR QUER ÜBER DEN
>   GROSSEN SYLTER DEICH.

But when create another component, say `go.mc` with a content

```
% $m->go('/page');
```

the internal redirect (the `go` method) somewhat mess up the content and will produce:

> A QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG. ÎÎÎÎ¦Î¥ÎÎÎÎ¤Î
>   ÎÎÎÎÎÎ Î¤Î ÎÎ©Î Î£ÎÎ£ ÎÎ Î ÎÎÎÎÎÎ Î¨Î¥Î§ÎÎÎ
>   Î¤Î¡ÎÎÎÎÎ¤Î. ÃRVÃZTÅ°RÅ TÃKÃRFÃRÃGÃP. DOÅÄ GRÃÅ¹B
>   FUZJÄ, KLNÄ, PYCH I MAÅÅ»EÅSTW! Ð­Ð¥, Ð§Ð£ÐÐÐ, ÐÐÐ©ÐÐ
>   Ð¡ÐªÐÐ Ð¦ÐÐ Ð¨ÐÐ¯Ð (Ð®Ð¤Ð¢Ð¬) â ÐÐÐ Ð«ÐÐ! KÅDEÄ½ Å
>   Å¤ASTNÃCH ÄATÄ½OV UÄÃ PRI ÃSTÃ VÃHU MÄ¹KVEHO KOÅA OBHRÃZAÅ¤
>   KÃRU A Å½RAÅ¤ ÄERSTVÃ MÃSO. ZWÃLF BOXKÃMPFER JAGEN VIKTOR QUER
>   ÃBER DEN GROSSEN SYLTER DEICH.

Strange, the `$m->visit()` works correctly. So, somewhere in Poet/Mason is need do something to get correct output for the `go` method.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Could please the down-voter tell me what is wrong with the question?

Answer (score 2):

I've been working on a plugin for Mason to deal with encoding. `$result->output` is the wrong place to encode output, because `visit` will run a subrequest, encoding its own content at the end, before returning to the original component, which then re-encodes everything when it completes. So the content in the `visit` gets encoded twice. I'm surprised you are having a problem with `go`, because that discards all previous content and starts again, which should be OK.

Have a look at https://github.com/davebaird/mason-plugin-withencoding